# Material Autocompletetextview shows error even when an item is selected

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

My code:

*xml:*

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout                         
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/caste_textinputlayout"
    android:hint="caste"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">
                                
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/caste_dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:focusable="false"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

*java:*

```
MaterialAutoCompleteTextView caste = findViewById(R.id.caste_dropdown);
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add("general");
arr.add("sc");
arr.add("st");
arr.add("obc");
arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,arr);
caste.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
submit.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    if (caste.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        caste.requestFocus();
        caste.setError("Please don't leave the field empty");
    }
});
```

---

When no item is selected in the dropdown, then the error shows, which it should. Now if I select an item, it still shows the error. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to `setError(null)`, when an item is selected:

```
caste.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> caste.setError(null));
```